# Azure Error 403 this site is stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a asp.net mvc5 site running off a azure website, its running off a D1 shared infrastructure.

In the last couple of days I've had a few issues when deploying to it. Its at times been unable to deploy. (i've hashed out my site name)

> Error 26  Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote
>   computer ("#####.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process
>   ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make
>   sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the
>   remote computer.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

And now when I deploy I'm getting

> Error 403 - This web app is stopped.

. When I look in the azure portal it says the site is running and I cannot see anything in the ftp logfiles\http\rawlogs\ which would indicate this issue. i.e. I can just see 200 responses from then the site was last responding.

Restarting the site via the portal doesnt seem to make a difference.

How can i diagnose the cause of this problem? and is it possible that it could be related to any changes i have made to my application rather than a server infrastructure issue?

Comment: I have the exact same problem :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be running into Quota issues if your site is in SHARED mode. Please try upgrading to STANDARD mode.

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Azure Error 403 azure quota e]

Comment: how do i diagnose these issues? I've upgraded to standard (temporarily) but the site doesn't surpass any quotas listed and thus i need to switch it back to shared once i establish what the issue is.

Comment: We ran into this as well.  Switching from Shared to Standard fixed it.  Then we switched right back to Shared, and things worked correctly again.  It seems possible that this bounced us to a different shared VM that wasn't misconfigured or with another misbehaving app like the previous one.

Comment: Same problem. Switched to standard S1 and the website worked again. Next I switched back to shared and it went back to the blue 403 screen. Next I switched to basic B1 and it seems to work again, but I'm paying over 5 times the price.

Comment: I've seen this as well recently. It seems that on Shared mode you can be vulnerable to problems from other users of that shared vm which you know nothing about and can't do anything about. Doesn't sound right, but there you are.

Comment: My site was in Basic mode (non-shared), but I had the same issue. I switched from B1 to S1 and the problem resolved itself. I then switched back to B1 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Our site wasn't in shared mode and scaling up/down to another service plan helped for a moment but the problem quickly recurred.

Turned out the staging environment was bad.

To fix the problem, I had to swap, delete the staging slot, and then wait ~30 minutes before I could recreate it (got errors saying the hostname still existed).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same deployment problem from Azure Devops and the site wasn't in shared mode.

```
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.    
Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC    
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("######.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.    
Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    
Error count: 1.    
Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
```

I wasn't able to get to the Kudu site (######.scm.azurewebsites.net) from my local machine but I was able to from a JumpBox VM in our Azure subscription.

After inspecting the settings at resources.azure.com I noticed that under the "web" settings:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{SiteName}/config/web?api-version=2018-02-01
```

The "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain" value was set to "true".  I set it back to "false" and was able to deploy and view Kudu locally again.